# Onload() handler not responding in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, svg

I'm creating a canvas and using drawImage() to draw an inline svg. Everything works okay but I'm stuck because of the below problem...

My problem is that the onload handler not responding in IE?? Rhis works in FF and chhrome. How do I fix it to work in IE 9 upwards?

```
img2.onload = function() {
     console.log("load");
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z769z7af/8/)

```
function createme() {
      var test = $('<canvas />', { id : 'mycanvs' })
      $('#album').append(test);

      var svg2 = document.getElementById('sSource').innerHTML,
          vms = test[0], //canvas
          ctx2 = vms.getContext('2d');

      svgToImage(svg2);

      function svgToImage(svg2) {
        var nurl = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(svg2),
            img2 = new Image;
          alert("just before onload")
          img2.onload = function() {
              console.log("load"); // does not show
          }
          img2.src = nurl;
      }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, fixing `charset=utf-8` got you part of the way towards creating an image from SVG. But...even though you **can** draw SVG to the canvas, in IE you **can't** export the canvas content to an image with `canvas.toDataURL` because of IE's security restrictions. Chrome & FF do not have such security restrictions and you can get the dataURL (and therefore create the image) with SVG content from those browsers.

Comment: @markE: thanks for your input. What's the solution if I need to be able to export canvas content to image in IE too?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct solution for IE because the canvas gets tainted immediately when the svg is drawn to it. Next best solution is to send the svg back to the server and convert it into a .png (which won't taint the canvas).

Comment: @markE: How would you recommend sending a svg to the server?

Comment: I presume you're creating the SVG on-the-fly in the client browser, otherwise you could just convert the SVG into a PNG and send the PNG instead.  Anyway, you can convert the SVG to a string using `XMLSerializer` and then send that SVG to the server using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an IE VM running at the moment, but according to [their docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the handler has to be defined before the object itself:

> To ensure that an event handler receives the onload event for these
>   objects, **place the script object that defines the event handler before
>   the object** and use the onload attribute in the object to set the
>   handler.

I don't see why your code wouldn't work in IE, but this fiddle tweaks it slightly so your handler is defined before you create the image object... give this a try:

```
function createme() {
      var test = $('<canvas />', { id : 'mycanvs' });
      var onloadHandler = function() {
          console.log("load");
      };
      $('#album').append(test);

      var svg2 = document.getElementById('sSource').innerHTML,
          vms = test[0], //canvas
          ctx2 = vms.getContext('2d');

      function svgToImage(svg2) {
        var nurl = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(svg2),
            img2 = new Image;

          img2.onload = onloadHandler

          img2.src = nurl;
      }
      svgToImage(svg2);
}
createme();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z769z7af/10/

Comment: thanks. :) But still doesn't work in IE. If you run it in IE you'll see for your self.

Comment: hm... I don't have the VM on this machine but I could look later... now that I am looking at the code again, I wonder if the missing `()` after `new Image` could be causing the issue?